# sortBy Spark Scala executes but not as expected

Tags: apache-spark

The following from another question on SO today, in which a descending sort was not gotten as per the following syntax:

```
val p=sc.parallelize(Seq(("abc",1),("def",2),("ghi",3),("jkl",4)))
val s=p.sortBy{x=>(x._2,false)}
```

The syntax here for, presumably, a descending sort of an RDD based on second tuple element is clearly not conform the general approach, but it does executes. On my machine I got what looks like an ascending sort, but the author of the original question did not, so may be my observation is by chance.

The correct syntax is:

```
val s2=p.sortBy(x=> x._2,false)
```

Why did the incorrect specification work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why did the incorrect specification work?

Because it is not invalid. This means

```
p.sortBy{x=>(x._2,false)}
```

generate keys of form

```
(x._2,false)
```

and then sort using these keys.

Tuple `(Int, Boolean)` has implicit `Ordering`, hence there is no reason for this code to fail

Comment: Yes I get the key generation but cannot relate it to the p.

Comment: Gotcha. Actually in sql terms fine as well. Silly me.